# How to differentiate between CXCursor_UnexposedExpr node types in Objective-C source file parsing?

Tags: objective-c, clang, llvm

I'm trying to write a test program to parse a Objective-C source file. When I encountered the CXCursor_UnexposedExpr node, it could represent a number of code types, for eg:

```
NSDictionary *testDict = @{@"testkey":@"testvalue"};
```

```
NSArray *testArray = @[@"value1",@"value2"];
```

They seem to have the same AST structure. For example, sample statements parse like this:

```
DeclStmt <{35:5}-{35:57}>-<:>
    VarDecl <{35:5}-{35:56}>-<testDict:>
        ObjCClassRef <{35:5}-{35:17}>-<NSDictionary:>
        UnexposedExpr <{35:30}-{35:56}>-<:>
            UnexposedExpr <{35:30}-{35:56}>-<:>
                UnexposedExpr <{35:30}-{35:56}>-<:>
                    UnexposedExpr <{35:32}-{35:42}>-<:>
                        ObjCStringLiteral <{35:32}-{35:42}>-<"testkey":>
                            StringLiteral <{35:33}-{35:42}>-<"testkey":>
                    UnexposedExpr <{35:43}-{35:55}>-<:>
                        ObjCStringLiteral <{35:43}-{35:55}>-<"testvalue":>
                            StringLiteral <{35:44}-{35:55}>-<"testvalue":>
```

and

```
DeclStmt <{37:5}-{37:49}>-<:>
    VarDecl <{37:5}-{37:48}>-<testArray:>
        ObjCClassRef <{37:5}-{37:12}>-<NSArray:>
        UnexposedExpr <{37:26}-{37:48}>-<:>
            UnexposedExpr <{37:26}-{37:48}>-<:>
                UnexposedExpr <{37:26}-{37:48}>-<:>
                    UnexposedExpr <{37:28}-{37:37}>-<:>
                        ObjCStringLiteral <{37:28}-{37:37}>-<"value1":>
                            StringLiteral <{37:29}-{37:37}>-<"value1":>
                    UnexposedExpr <{37:38}-{37:47}>-<:>
                        ObjCStringLiteral <{37:38}-{37:47}>-<"value2":>
                            StringLiteral <{37:39}-{37:47}>-<"value2":>
```

When I parse with clang -fsyntax-only -Xclang -ast-dump, the output from the console looks like this:
[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2gd5.jpg)

How should I tell them apart?

Am I overlooking something or should I handle this code in a different way？